# SELECT list inconsistent with GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle

I don't seem to figure this one out. I am trying to run this query where I am suppose to get two columns; one column gets me the first and last name, the second column gets me the number of "authorid" which would represent books written by that author. If I add the count(authorid) in the first line it displays the error message shown below. Thank you very much in advance.

```
 SELECT FNAME || ' ' || LNAME "Author", AUTHORID
 FROM BOOKAUTHOR JOIN AUTHOR USING(AUTHORID)
 ORDER BY FNAME;
```

=================================================================================

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
SELECT FNAME || ' ' || LNAME "Author", count(AUTHORID)
FROM BOOKAUTHOR JOIN AUTHOR USING(AUTHORID)
ORDER BY FNAME
Error at Command Line : 2 Column : 41
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01748: only simple column names allowed here
01748. 00000 -  "only simple column names allowed here"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

=================================================================================

```
     The output should look like the lines below

Author                   Books Written
========================================
John Doe                      3
James Row                     2
```

Comment: Are you missing your `GROUP BY`?

Comment: Yes, Sir. I am sorry I got it mixed up. I will update the output that I get when running that query.

Comment: What resarch did you do prior to asking on SO? `A simpleColumnName is used to represent a column when it cannot be qualified by a tableName orbcorrelationName. This is the case when the qualification is fixed, as it is in a column definition within a CREATE TABLE statement.` is what the [manual on `simpleColumnName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefsimplecolumnname.htm) tells me. Use `USING(AUTHORID)` instead if the columns are equally named in both tables or `ON BOOKAUTHOR.AUTHORID = AUTHOR.ID` (assuming the column is called `ID`).

Comment: Actually this is my first class of SQL and I have been reviewing my notes. However, I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're including `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT A.FNAME || ' ' || A.LNAME "Author", count(A.AUTHORID)
FROM BOOKAUTHOR BA
  JOIN AUTHOR A ON BA.AUTHORID = A.AUTHORID
GROUP BY A.FNAME || ' ' || A.LNAME
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d14a8/2)

Comment: You nailed it sgeddes!. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your failing statement has this:

```
USING(AUTHOR.AUTHORID)
```

But you are only allowed to have:

```
USING(AUTHORID)
```

Try this:

```
SELECT AUTHOR.FNAME || ' ' || AUTHOR.LNAME "Author", count(AUTHOR.AUTHORID)
FROM BOOKAUTHOR JOIN AUTHOR USING(AUTHORID)
GROUP BY AUTHOR.FNAME, AUTHOR.LNAME
ORDER BY AUTHOR.FNAME
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help WW. After running your query I got the following:

Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 60
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-25154: column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier
25154. 00000 -  "column part of USING clause cannot have qualifier"
*Cause:    Columns that are used for a named-join (either a NATURAL join
           or a join with a USING clause) cannot have an explicit qualifier.
*Action:   Remove the qualifier.